# Wirless Card chipset

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I want to know the chipset of my wireless card on Lenovo t410i.
I ran this command:

```
lspci -vv -s 03:00.0
```

with this result:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device e020
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Region 1: Memory at f2400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
    Kernel modules: rtl8192se
```

From these lines, can I find the chipset?

Comment: Isn't this all there is to know? `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB` What more are you looking for?

Comment: @chili555 so the chipset is RTL8191SEvB?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It appears also that you have a working driver `rtl8192se`. Is everything working as expected? Is there some issue we can assist you with?

Comment: I'm getting information about aircrack-ng. What is the connection between drivers and chipset?

Comment: The RTL8191SE is your "chipset". See the Realtek product page: http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=226.

Comment: The chipset is the physical silicon chip. The driver is a bit of software that bridges the chip and the operating system. I doubt that aircrack cares about the chipset but wants the driver, in your case`rtl8192se`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the first row. In your case this would be **RTL8191SEvB**.

If you run `lspci` with switch `-nn` instead of `-vv` you will find vendor and device ID in a hexadecimal format encapsulated in square brackets. This could further help identifying your hardware with a bit of Google-jutsu. An example from my own system:

```
lspci -nn -s 00:19.0
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
```

From this output you can read my vendor and device id is **[8086:1503]**.